# Python bubble sort not sorting the entire list

Tags: python, bubble-sort

Its sorting only the half of list i have debugged but not getting to work.

```
mylist = [16, 19, 11, 15, 10, 12, 14]

for j in range(len(mylist)):   
    isSwapped = False
    i = 0
    while i<len(mylist)-1:      
        if mylist[i]>mylist[i + 1]:
            mylist[i], mylist[i + 1] = mylist[i + 1], mylist[i]          
            isSwapped = True
        else:
            isSwapped = False
        i = i+1
    if isSwapped == False:
        break
print (mylist)
```

## Currrent output

`[11, 15, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19]`

wanted to complete list to be sorted
any hint or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: are you sure that if a swap does not occur that you should end the sort?

Comment: `else:
            isSwapped = False` are you sure you need this?

Comment: `isSwapped` is always just the result of whether the last two numbers were swapped. @n.m. says, you shouldn't reset it there - just use the one outside the `while` loop